# Encode/Hide the RequestParameters of url in spring mvc

Tags: spring

I am using spring 3.2 with jsp as a view resolver. I have one HTML table with multiple view hyperlinks.
For hyperlinks i used

a href="edit"?id=1

When ever i use anchor tag spring controller takes GET method as default.
My requirement is hide the  request parameters or encode the parameters.

Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Adding request parameters to url for GET is standard behaviour, use POST or make it asynchronous with Ajax

Comment: thanks for reply if i use Ajax the response will come with in same page ..but in my case when click on hyperlink i have to forward to another page. and POST request is not allowing, it is anchor tag it default taken as GET only..please give any other suggestion.

Comment: What do you gain by encoding it? IMHO just complexity, if someone has the url or encoded id they can still do the same. The only thing you get as a benefit is that you don't have, directyly, readable ids in your uri...

Comment: @user3719245 Well you can't achive everything: changing page, getting new query parameter and hide it. Maybe instead of anchors, do small forms with POST

Comment: @Deinum :Thanks for reply.  My client wants hide the request parameters or encode the parameters. is it possible in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Something as below

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

Or you use javascript on jsp file:

```
var userInput = $("#myInput").val();            
var encodedUserInput = encodeURIComponent(userInput);
$("#hiddenImput").val(encodedUserInput);
```

and after recover on class:

```
String parameter = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("hiddenImput"), "UTF-8");
```